# Expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy elaborando un intérprete con expresiones regulares, ahorita estoy trabado, el problema es que quiero recordar un patrón más de 1 vez:

```
^(${name})${descrip.rules.skip}+(${descrip.rules.assig})${descrip.rules.skip}*(${name}|${type.decimal}|${type.num}|${type.vof}|${type.texto})${descrip.rules.skip}*(?:(\\+|-|\\/|%)${descrip.rules.skip}*(${name}|${type.decimal}|${type.num}|${type.vof}|${type.texto}))*${descrip.rules.skip}*!$
```

Al final uso 3 paréntesis:

1. es todo el patrón que quiero recordar pero le puse ?: para que no
   sea así
2. el puro operador
3. el valor

Ahora quiero recordar una operaciín así: `5+4/2`

Pero lo que me recuerda sólo es : `5/2`

¿alguna idea de como hacer que recuerde lo demás?

Comment: Entiendo que cosas como esta: `${type.texto}` son variables o subpatrones. Hay alguna manera de que nos puedas escribir la expresión regular completa, una vez se han interpolado estos subpatrones o variables?

Comment: `/\s*(\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\b)\s*(->)\s*(\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\b|\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b|\b[0-9]+\b|verdadero|falso|".*"|'.*')\s*(?:(\+|-|\/|%)\s*(\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\b|\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b|\b[0-9]+\b|verdadero|falso|".*"|'.*'))+\s*!$/g`

Comment: espero que se entienda, es para validar la asignacion a una variable, pero quiero que se puedan hacer multiples operaciones

Comment: Efectivamente es lo que imaginaba. Revisa mi respuesta, ahí detallo el problema que tienes

Comment: ¿Puedes poner casos de prueba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para explicarme lo haré con un ejemplo más sencillo.

El problema es que estás machacando los grupos de captura con búsquedas posteriores.

Por ejemplo, considera la siguiente entrada `5-4-2` y la expresión regular: `(\d)(?:(-)(\d))+` que solo buscaría números y signo de restar (pero que funciona de la misma manera que tu expresión)

- El primer grupo es el primer número
- El segundo grupo es la operación (para simplificar, siempre resta)
- El tercer grupo es el siguiente número

El problema es que con esta expresión: `(?:(-)(\d))+` capturas `-4`, pero como se puede repetir por el `+`, luego capturas `-2` y machacas los valores que tenías 
en el segundo y tercer grupo de captura. Siempre te quedas con lo último.

Así pues, después de ejecutarlo, el primer grupo tendría `5`, el segundo `-` y el tercero `2`

**[Ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/Gp0Wvs/1/)**

Una posible alternativa sería capturar el conjunto completo de operaciones y luego ir realizando búsquedas con un bucle. Por ejemplo, para el ejemplo simplificado:

Buscaríamos: `(\d)((?:-\d)+)`

Ahora el segundo grupo tiene `-4-2`, que guardaremos en una variable. Ahora realizaremos una nueva búsqueda en esa nueva variable por `(-)(\d)` (con flag global `g`) y para cada iteración guardaremos el grupo 1 y 2 en alguna variable (como un array)

Aquí tienes todo el proceso (simplificado) con javascript:

```js
let match = '5-4-2'.match(/(\d)((?:-\d)+)/);

let primero = match[1];
let segundo = match[2];

console.log('La segunda parte es: ' + segundo + ', Vamos a procesarla');

let operaciones = [];
let index_operaciones = 0;

const regexsegundo = /(-)(\d)/g;

while ((m = regexsegundo.exec(segundo)) !== null) {
    // Para evitar bucles infinitos con búsquedas de longitud 0
    // Si no es tu caso, puedes quitar este IF
    if (m.index === regexsegundo.lastIndex) {
        regexsegundo.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    operaciones[index_operaciones] = [];
    operaciones[index_operaciones][0] = m[1];
    operaciones[index_operaciones][1] = m[2];
    index_operaciones++
}

console.log('Resultados_________________');
console.log('Primero = ' + primero);
console.log('Luego = ');
console.log(operaciones);
```